# Reload Owl Carousel 2 when side navigation opens or closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

I am working on a website, and it is built off a theme. In the body of the site is structured to have a left-panel div which houses the navigation and a right-panel div which houses the body content.

When the left-panel opens from a collapsed view (showing only icons) to the full view (showing the nav text), owl-carousel, since it's loaded on page load, doesn't readjust the width.

I've tried a few methods to try and reload the carousel, following [their API](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html), but am not successful. The body doesn't have a set width, such as inline styles, but instead the class `left-menu-open` is set, when the left menu is open.

I've also looked at several other cases of people trying to do the same thing, but none of their code examples work.

Below is my code. I am running this in a .php file, so I am able to load multiple sliders in the body content, without them rotating in relation. The carousel loads and functions fine, it's just that it begins to clip if the page is loaded with the nav open and one closes the nav, or the 3rd slide shows if the page is loaded with the nav closed and is opened.

One method I've tried is

`if ( $( 'body' ).resize() { }`

`if ( $( 'body' ).hasClass( 'left-nav-open' ) { } else if ( !$( 'body ').resize() { }`

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var $owl = $('.owl-<?php echo $owl_widget_title; ?>');

    $owl.owlCarousel({
      // your initial option here, again.
      loop:true,
      nav:true,
      navText: ["<i class=\"fa fa-chevron-left\"></i>","<i class=\"fa fa-chevron-right\"></i>"],
      dots: false,
      lazyLoad: true,
      lazyContent: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 1000,
      autoplayTimeout: 7000,
      autoplayHoverPause: true,
      responsive : {
        0 : {
          items: 1,
          slideBy: 1,
          autoHeight:true,
        },
        992 : {
          items: <?php echo $num_of_items; ?>,
          slideBy: <?php echo $num_of_items; ?>,
        }
      }
    });

  });

})(jQuery)
```

I've tried `destroy.owl.carousel`, and then `initialize.owl.carousel` but neither of those seem to work or run at all.

Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update owl after resize of container one would need to call `.onResize()` *_handler* on its `data`. The `updateOwl()` function should look like this:

```
updateOwl = function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").each(function() {
    $(this).data('owl.carousel').onResize();
  });
};
```

The only thing to watch for is *when **exactly** to call this function*. I assume the sidebar is not jumping into position, but rather smoothly animating. The call to `.onResize()` needs to be delayed by the duration of animation, so the size of the carousel is calculated based on final content size. Delay the execution of `updateOwl()` by wrapping it into a `setTimeout()` (equal or slightly longer than the sidebar animation duration):

```
$(document).on('click', '.sidebarToggle', function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    updateOwl();        
  },   321)
});
```

...where `.sidebarToggle` would be your sidebar opener.

Working example:

```js
(function($) {
  var $owl = $('.owl-carousel'),
      updateOwl = function(){
        $owl.each(function() {
          $(this).data('owl.carousel').onResize();
        });
      };
  
  $owl.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'],
    dots: false,
    lazyLoad: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    autoplayTimeout: 7000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
        slideBy: 1,
        autoHeight: true,
      },
      992: {
        items: 3,
        slideBy: 3,
      }
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.sidebarToggle', function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('sidebarOpen'); 
    setTimeout(function(){
      updateOwl();        
    }, 321)
  });

  $(window).on('resize', updateOwl); 
  
})(jQuery)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  transition: padding-left .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  }
.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #888;
  left: -200px;
  top:0;
  transition: left .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebarOpen .sidebar {
  left: 0;
}

body.sidebarOpen {
  padding-left: 200px;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  padding: 0 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item > div{
  min-height: 135px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: Gainsboro;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
button {
  margin: 15px;
}
.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
}
.owl-nav >div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
.owl-prev {left: 20px}
.owl-next {left: calc(100% - 20px);}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<div class="sidebar"></div>

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
</div>
<button class="sidebarToggle">SidebarToggle</button>
```

If the above is not working for you, I'll need to have a look at your implementation to be able to debug it.

**Side note:** `lazyContent` is currently unavailable. According to plugin author:

> ...`lazyContent` was introduced during beta tests but i removed it from the final release due to bad implementation. It is a nice options so i will work on it in the nearest feature.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, and I hope you receive the bounty. I have been away for a long while. This does perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: As per current site rules I received half, but I'm not here for rep. I picked up coding rather late and owe my skills to communities like this one. It feels good to give back

Answer (score 1):

I use `destroy.owl.carousel` to destroy carousel. Carousel reinitialize on click of left navigation menu

```js
var $owl = $('.owl-carousel');
/*inital on load */
$owl.owlCarousel({
  items: 6,
  lazyLoad: true,
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
});
/*on click of navigation menu */
function resizeCarosel(obj) {
  if (obj.classList.contains('is-open')) {
    $owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel'); /*destroy Carousel*/
    $owl.owlCarousel({ /*reinitialize Carousel*/
      items: 6,
      lazyLoad: true,
      loop: true,
      margin: 10,
    });
  }
  if (obj.classList.contains('is-closed')) {
    $owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel'); /*destroy Carousel*/
    $owl.owlCarousel({ /*reinitialize Carousel*/
      items: 2,
      lazyLoad: true,
      loop: true,
      margin: 10,
      /*for responsive 
        items: 4,
        responsiveClass: true,
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1,
            nav: true
          },
          600: {
            items: 3,
            nav: false
          },
          1000: {
            items: 5,
            nav: true,
            loop: false
          }
        }
      */
    });
  }

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/FragCoder/bootstrap-left-slide-menu/master/bootstrap-left-slide-menu.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/FragCoder/bootstrap-left-slide-menu/master/bootstrap-left-slide-menu.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/dist/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper" class="">
  <div class="overlay" style="display: none;"></div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#"> BLESM </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> Photo</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></i> Video</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></i> Music</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></i> Cloud</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i> Apps</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> Settings</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="hamburger animated fadeInLeft is-closed" data-toggle="offcanvas" onclick="resizeCarosel(this)">
      <span class="hamb-top"></span>
      <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
      <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=1" data-src-retina="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=1-retina" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=2" data-src-retina="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=2-retina" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=3" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=4" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=5" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=6" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=7" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=8" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=9" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=10" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="https://placehold.it/350x250&text=11" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue I see with your solution, is the issue I am running into, the animation is resizing the body, so while it does shrink or go down from 6 to 2, the second block is still half rendered.

Comment: your problem is for rendering or reloading(reinitialize)

Comment: I don't think so in OwlCarousel2 they change the container for responsive . you can see [full screen](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/wLntqfwt/show/) vs [edit view](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/wLntqfwt) of responsive OwlCarousel2 example

Comment: So in essence, there is no way to deal with this. I've tried your code, then modifying it to reinit the container when the navigation opens, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the job done by simple deleting the element from the DOM (jquery has a function .remove()) and then recreating exactly as you did with the first one. Notice that you will have to store the variables that come from the server in the client.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Setting the elements to a variable? Past experience, and I may be wrong on it, has shown that the DOM doesn't really actually store it when I use it. So if I open the inspected, head to console, and log out a variable, it says undefined

Comment: echoing all the server side variables into js variables.

Comment: When I do this, the DOM doesn't recognize any of the saved variables.

Answer (score -1):

1. I propose to trigger [the `refresh.owl.carousel` event](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html#refresh-owl-carousel).
2. My sidebar uses transition so I need to detect [the `transitionend` event](https://jonsuh.com/blog/detect-the-end-of-css-animations-and-transitions-with-javascript/#detecting-and-executing-when-transitions-end-with-jquery).
3. I've set the `.main` block as [the `responsiveBaseElement`](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#responsivebaseelement). Now the carousel adjusts to the width of its container, and not to the width of the entire page.
4. And I've added a few more jump points to make the responsive changes more
   visible.

Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/zwozRx

```js
var $owl = $('#myCarousel');
var owl = $owl.owlCarousel({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  dots: false,
  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  navText: [ "<i class=\"fa fa-chevron-left\"></i>",
             "<i class=\"fa fa-chevron-right\"></i>" ],
  responsiveBaseElement: '.main',
  responsive : {
    0 : {
      items: 1,
      slideBy: 1,
    },
    400 : {
      items: 2,
      slideBy: 1,
    },
    768 : {
      items: 3,
      slideBy: 2,
    },
    992 : {
      items: 4,
      slideBy: 2,
    },
    1200 : {
      items: 5,
      slideBy: 2,
    },
  },
});

$('.sidebar-switcher').click(function(){
  $('body').toggleClass( 'body-open' );
  $('.main').one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", function(event) {
    owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
  });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/** sidebar closed **/
.main,
.sidebar {
  -webkit-transition: margin .4s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: margin .4s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: margin .4s ease-out;
       -o-transition: margin .4s ease-out;
          transition: margin .4s ease-out;
}
.main {
  padding: 0 36px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
.sidebar {
  background: #ccc;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -230px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
.sidebar-switcher {
  position: absolute; top: 12px; right: 12px;
}
.sidebar-switcher:before {
  content: '\f0c9';
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute; top: 12px; right: 12px;
}

/** sidebar opened **/
.body-open .main {
  margin-left: 300px;
}
.body-open .sidebar {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.body-open .sidebar-switcher:before {
  content: '\f00d';
}

/** owl carousel **/
.owl-item > div {
  margin: 12px;
}
.owl-next,
.owl-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 36px;
  bottom: 0; 
}
.owl-next {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -12px;
}
.owl-prev {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: -12px;
}
.owl-next i,
.owl-prev i {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
.owl-next i {
  left: 12px;
}
.owl-prev i {
  right: 12px;
}
.owl-next:hover i,
.owl-prev:hover i {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-switcher"></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="owl-carousel" id="myCarousel">
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/fc3/fff/?text=1" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/693/fff/?text=2" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/369/fff/?text=3" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/f63/fff/?text=4" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/936/fff/?text=5" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Who put the "minus", please explain why.